# Figma/Adobe XD integration with Adobe Target

Tags: adobe, target, figma, adobe-xd

Is there any way to connect(import) Figma/AdobeXD UX designs to Adobe Target(Offers).

**Actual Requirement**

Business wants to export designs from Figma or Adobe XD to Adobe Target and convert them in offers.

And these offers will be used in activities.

I Did not found any document for same